# How to make groups/hidden rows behave like filtered lists so changes only affect visible cells, to prevent accidental data loss?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When rows/columns are hidden in a group or by manually hiding rows/columns, and cells are highlighted like so

[image]

[image]

If formatting is applied, or something is deleted, it applies to the hidden sections too, e.g.

[image]

[image]

When you do this on filtered lists though, only visible rows are affected

I want to include some groups in a spreadsheet, but I'm worried about the potential for data loss.  Is there some way to change the behavior of groups so that this can't happen, or some other workaround that allows me to have easily expandable/collapsible sets of hidden cells that can't be wiped when invisible by mistake?